# Spring 2.0 Annotations and ant

Tags: spring, ant, annotations, javac

I have an old appfuse project, running Spring 2.0, and Java 1.6, and I'm trying to get Transaction annotation support (and other annotations) running.

But, when I add this to our class:

```
@Transactional
public class ... {
}
```

We get an ant compile issue, like:

```
[javac] symbol: class Transactional
[javac] @Transactional
[javac]  ^
```

How do I tell ant which Spring transactions it should be using?

Comment: I am curious to know if you are targeting java 1.5+ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a simple import problem to me. Have you imported the class `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`:

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
```

Annotations are classes which must be imported to be used (without using their fully qualified name), just as any other class.

Comment: A minor nitpick: Annotation types are actually interfaces, not classes.

Comment: That did it, easy enough.  Thanks!