# Transactions in Spring / Hibernate / appfuse

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, transactional, appfuse

As a follow up to the question here:  [Spring 2.0 Annotations and ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141032/spring-2-0-annotations-and-ant)

We were able to get the annotations working (@Transactional), and also tried manually coding a Transaction.

In both cases, we are getting some problems.  This is an appfuse 1.9.4 project, where we manually upgraded to a newer Hibernate project.  This is using Spring 2.0.

What I'd like to do is to wrap an entire web service in a database "Transaction", so that the entire "call" is atomic.  I understand that the "easiest" way to do this is with @Transactional?

To do so, we added to our class:

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
```

And then, next to the method (which is public), we did:

```
@Transactional (readOnly = false, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public List processEmployees(List employees){
  ....
}
```

In to applicationContext-hibernate.xml, I added:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

Now, when I start Tomcat, I get this lovely error:

```
[Scheduler] 2011-08-22 12:57:03,032 ERROR [main] ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(205) | Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 153 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-hibernate.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "tx" for element "tx:annotation-driven" is not bound.
Caused by: 
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "tx" for element "tx:annotation-driven" is not bound.
```

We are using Spring 2.0, but do not have any AOP "configured".

Any ideas?

Alternatively, I'm happy to do this with Transaction.commit(), but going that route throws a message about the transaction never being started.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't define the ["tx" namespace](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-tx) in your `applicationContext-hibernate.xml`. Thus the XML parser can't identify the element.

Comment: That did it as well.  I'm too far removed from web app development anymore, it would certainly seem.  Thanks!